# My nav tabs are removing elements

Tags: javascript, html

so I am making a page with three nav tabs on the left and a map on the right. I have my code here for the nav tabs. On the first tab I want a field where the user can enter some info and the map will adjust accordingly. It works fine once the page loads, but if I visit another tab and come back then the input field will be gone. Any ideas?

```
<div class="tabbable" class='span4'> <!-- Only required for left/right tabs -->
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li id='tab1' class="active"><a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab">Browse</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab">History</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab3" data-toggle="tab">Wishlist</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="tab-content">

    <!-- Browse tab -->
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab1">
      <form class="form-search">
        <input type="text" class="input-medium search-query" id='location'>
        <button type="submit" class="btn">Search</button>
        <p><b>Find brewery by name..</b></p>
      </form>
    </div><!-- end Browse Tab -->

    <!-- History tab -->
    <div class="tab-pane" id="tab2">
      <p>I've been here!</p>
    </div><!-- end History tab -->

    <!-- Wishlist tab -->
    <div class="tab-pane" id="tab3">
      <p>We still have to check these places out!</p>
    </div><!-- end Wishlist tab -->

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can You post jsfiddle or link to live demo?

Comment: Not too familiar with JFiddle. I just tried to put the code in there but it is not giving me the same result I have in my app.

Answer (score 0):

Since your nav links are `a` tags using anchors in their `href`, the page is reloaded on click. A page reload will reset any entered form information.

Comment: Is there a way to do it where I do not have to refresh? Should I change the a tags to something else?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to do it where I do not have to refresh? Should I change the a tags to something else?

Yes like this (looks ugly, works great IMO):

```
<a href="javascript:;"></a>
```

alternatively, with HTML5 you can leave out the href altogether

```
<a></a>
```

but...I wouldn't recommend that, probably some backwards compatibility issues.

After re-reading your original question though I don't think this is the root of the problem, hard to tell without a live example though.